# Why does pydoc say "any" is a package? I thought any() was a function

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I thought I would try using pydoc to give me a description of each built-in function.  But when I run `pydoc any`, it returns:

```
Help on package any:

NAME
    any

PACKAGE CONTENTS


FILE
    (built-in)
```

However, `pydoc builtins` has a FUNCTIONS section which has what I was looking for:

```
any(iterable, /)
    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

    If the iterable is empty, return False.
```

In perl, you can run e.g., `perldoc -tf open` to see the documentation for the `open()` function.

I was expecting similar functionality in Python, especially given this text from pydoc help:

```
pydoc <name> ...
    Show text documentation on something.  <name> may be the name of a
    Python keyword, topic, function, module, or package, or a dotted
    reference to a class or function within a module or module in a
    package.  If <name> contains a '/', it is used as the path to a
    Python source file to document. If name is 'keywords', 'topics',
    or 'modules', a listing of these things is displayed.
```

To recap, `any()` is a function but `pydoc any` doesn't show me the documentation for the `any()` function.  Instead I have to dig inside the `pydoc builtins` output which is quite large.

Is there a Python equivalent to `perldoc -tf` where I can pull out documentation for a single function?

Comment: `python -m pydoc any` works on my Python 3.11.3, displaying "Help on built-in function any in module builtins".

Comment: Python 3.11.6 on Ubuntu also only prints the `any` function documentation for `pydoc any`.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the comments from @enzo and @Robert yesterday, I tried it again on my Debian-based laptop and it works fine:

```
[:~] [my-venv] 1 $ py
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  2 2023, 13:45:54) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
[:~] [my-venv] $ pydoc any
Help on built-in function any in module builtins:

any(iterable, /)
    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

    If the iterable is empty, return False.

[:~] [my-venv] $
```

I tried it on my work laptop (macOS with brew installed python) and it works fine there.

So now I'm really confused how and where it did not work yesterday, but that's a different question.  I guess I am all set now and I can look up documentation for functions. Thanks!